# Query to get First Value and Second value with Filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following need but I am not able to get an effective query:

| ID | DATE | PARCEL | STATUS | TYPE | DT_PAY | DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-15 | 28 | 3 | R | 2021-10-15 | 2021-10-15 |
| 2 | 2021-11-15 | 29 | 0 | R | 1900-01-01 | 2021-11-15 |
| 3 | 2021-12-15 | 30 | 3 | R | 2021-12-15 | 2021-12-15 |
| 4 | 2022-01-15 | 31 | 3 | R | 2022-01-15 | 2022-01-15 |
| 5 | 2022-02-15 | 32 | 3 | R | 2022-02-15 | 2022-02-15 |
| 6 | 2022-03-15 | 33 | 0 | R | 1900-01-01 | 2022-03-15 |
| 7 | 2022-04-15 | 34 | 0 | R | 1900-01-01 | 2022-04-15 |
| 8 | 2022-05-15 | 35 | 0 | R | 1900-01-01 | 2022-05-15 |
| 9 | 2022-06-15 | 36 | 0 | R | 1900-01-01 | 2022-06-15 |
| 10 | 2022-07-15 | 37 | 3 | R | 2022-07-15 | 2022-07-15 |

With the data in the table above you would need the following result:

| ID | DATE | PARCEL | STATUS | TYPE | DT_PAY | DT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 2022-03-15 | 33 | 0 | R | 1900-01-01 | 2022-03-15 |
| 2 | 2021-11-15 | 29 | 0 | R | 1900-01-01 | 2021-11-15 |

It is necessary to list the first occurrence of a line where STATUS = 0 appears after a line with STATUS = 3 appears, and the second time this occurs after another line appears with STATUS = 3 as well, but being from the most current to the oldest date, in this case the date 2022-03-15 is more current and the date 2021-11-15 is more old one that meets the STATUS = 0 filter appears after a line with STATUS = 3 appears

My query only works to find STATUS=3, but needed it to be the same for STATUS=0

```
with TopDates as

 (select row_number() over (order by DT desc) as Row, *

 from DBO.TABLE 
 WHERE DT < GETDATE ()
 AND DT_PAY <> '1900-01-01'
 AND STATUS = '3'
 )

 select 
       TB.ID
          ,TB.DATE
          ,TB.PARCEL
      ,TB.STATUS     
      ,TB.DT_PAY
          ,TB.DT
from TopDates TB
where Row<=2
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add an OR clause in there?
Or am I not understanding you correctly?

```
`with TopDates as

 (select row_number() over (order by DT desc) as Row, *

 from DBO.TABLE 
 WHERE DT < GETDATE ()
 AND DT_PAY <> '1900-01-01'
 AND STATUS = '3'
 OR STATUS = '0'
 )

 select 
       TB.ID
          ,TB.DATE
          ,TB.PARCEL
      ,TB.STATUS     
      ,TB.DT_PAY
          ,TB.DT
from TopDates TB
where Row<=2
```

Comment: So, thanks for the tip but it didn't work the result should be as I explained above where only the two lines of ID 6 and 2 should come and using the 'AND' the 'OR' did not bring this result.